# Getting enviornment variables into my build of my SolidJS app

Tags: vite, solid-js

In a SolidJS template I have:

```
          {import.meta.env["VITE_VARIABLE_NAME"]}
```

and this works fine when I run

```
npm start
```

(which in package.js just runs `vite`)

When I try to do `npm build` (which is `vite build` in package.js) it throws the following error:

```
Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
file: /file/path/here/src/App.tsx:52:26
50:         <div id="search-area">
51:           <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
52:           {import.meta.env["VITE_VARIABLE_NAME"]}
                              ^
53:           <input type="submit" id="search-button" value="Search" />
54:         </div>
error during build:
RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
```

How do I get this to just put in the value for the variable in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const VITE_VARIABLE_NAME = import.meta.env["VITE_VARIABLE_NAME"]

export function App() {
  return (
        <div id="search-area">
           <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
           {VITE_VARIABLE_NAME }
                              ^
           <input type="submit" id="search-button" value="Search" />
         </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Nice, this works, but any explanation on why it didn't work before?

Comment: To understand this you need experience with template compilers